# ubuntu software center not working after update

Tags: upgrade, software-center

Today, I updated my Ubuntu (I have KDE Desktop installed on it before) and after the update, Ubuntu Software Center said: *Items cannot be installed or removed until the package catalog is repaired. Do you want to repair it?*; and when I'm clicked on Repair, after 2 seconds it says:

The installation or removal of software package Failed , with this details :

```
installArchives() failed: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kdm:
 kdm depends on libkworkspace4abi1 (= 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1); however:
  Version of libkworkspace4abi1 on system is 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2.
 kdm depends on kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins (= 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1); however:
  Version of kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins on system is 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2.
dpkg: error processing kdm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kubuntu-desktop:
 kubuntu-desktop depends on kdm; however:
  Package kdm is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing kubuntu-desktop (--configure):
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kdm
 kubuntu-desktop
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kdm:
 kdm depends on libkworkspace4abi1 (= 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1); however:
  Version of libkworkspace4abi1 on system is 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2.
 kdm depends on kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins (= 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1); however:
  Version of kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins on system is 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.2.
dpkg: error processing kdm (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kubuntu-desktop:
 kubuntu-desktop depends on kdm; however:
  Package kdm is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing kubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt-get -f install` in a terminal. That should repair your dependencies.

Comment: i tried it but my issue is it even can't remove & my problem isn't fixed !

Comment: @HOS Could you please edit your question and write the output of the command you ran?